# How to remove <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> tag from the Wso2 soap+xml output?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

here I have used


to convert my json to SOAP.
But automatically  is being added in the output.
I want to remove it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are using xslt mediator your can check  disable-output-escaping="no" flag from https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/XSLT+Mediator